# Windows Phone 8. Deep Toast

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, parse-platform, mpns

I'm developing Windows Phone 8 application which uses Parse.com as a Mobile Backend for send/receive Push Notifications.

The problem I'm worried about is how to make application, which is not launched to navigate to a specific page when I tap on the toast notification, which was sent by service.

for example it must navigate to "/Views/SearchPage.xaml", but not to a default page.

Also I have a notification channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send the toast notification from your server (parse.com in this case) you need to specify the app url of navigation `/Views/SearchPage.xaml` in a parameter called wp:param in the notification XML generated.

I didn't use Parse.com as backend, but reading the docs, seems like you can create a dictionary (value/key) of data to send. Maybe you can include the param/wp:param parameter [with the url value](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-data/iOS):

> It is also possible to specify your own data in this dictionary. As we'll see in the Receiving Notifications section, you will have access to this data only when the user opens your app via the notification. This can be useful for displaying a different view controller when a user opens certain notifications.

Hope this helps you.